# UIView's content blurry when I center it

Tags: ios, uiview

I have `UIView` that isn't big as the whole screen and I want it to appear in the middle of the screen. I did that with the following code:

```
    self.dialogView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2.0, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2.0);
```

Unfortunately, when I center it like that, `UIView`'s content appears blurry. 
[image]

I've fixed it with this:

```
    self.dialogView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2.0 + 0.5, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2.0);
```

Now UIView's content appears as it should :)

[image]

Can you tell me why that content becomes blurry and why I need to add 0.5 to the left position offset?

Comment: Does it happen with non-Retina displays too ?

Comment: @A-Live: Pictures in the question are from non-Retina iPhone simulator. On retina it isn't blurry.

Comment: Right, naturally plus one point to Retina for using view's center.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The new center is causing the origin of the control's view to fall on a half-pixel, like { 20.5, 20.5 }. Since the screen can't draw only half a pixel, the rendering engine attempts to get the same effect by diffusing the image as best it can, resulting in blurry images.

You need to make sure all your views' origins are whole numbers.

Comment: Yeah, I've made sure that center isn't on half-pixel, but I've forgotten to check the origin :) Thanks!

Comment: @xx77aBs Yeah, it's actually not the center that's important, because if the width of a thing is 15, for example, the center x of the thing would naturally be 7.5 (assuming the origin is 0), this is okay. But the origin must be a whole number so the entire view is pixel-aligned ;)

Comment: An easy way to force your frame to whole numbers is by using CGRectIntegral.

Answer (score 1):

well i think thats due to how the `UIView` is being placed on the pixel grid of the screen. if you think about it on regular screens (72 px/inch), 0.5 points means 0.5 pixels which would probably cause what you see... thats my theory at least :P